# How to fix succes Call Back not executing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am integrating payment gateway to my ionic 3 project. It has successcallback function when the payment made successful. But inside the successcallback function i can only able to alert the result nothing else is working.

```
RazorpayCheckout.open(options, this.successCallback, this.cancelCallback);


//this works
successCallback(payment_id)
  {
    alert(pament_id);
  }

//this not working
successCallback(payment_id)
  {

     let loading = this.loadingController.create({
     spinner: 'circles'
  });

  loading.present();


  this.update[ayment(payment_id);

  loading.dismiss();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so that the context of `this` gets properly binded.

```
successCallback = (payment_id) => {

  let loading = this.loadingController.create({
     spinner: 'circles'
  });

  loading.present();
  this.updatePayment(payment_id);
  loading.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: @Ananth Glad to help :)